# write regex c #

Tags: c#

write a regular expression for taxi numbers in Belarus

1)region code (a digit from 1 to 7);

2)three uppercase Latin letters. For the `7' region (Minsk), the combinations TAX, TBX, TEX are used, for other regions, only TAX, TBX are currently in use;

3)a single space;

4)four-digit number from 1 to 9999, with leading zeroes.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Please show us what you have tried, what isn't working and expected output for us to help you further.

Comment: This seems to be just an assignment, we expect to see an actual question.

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: ^[1-7][TABEX]{3}\s[0-9]{4}$

Comment: But for 7 it should output TAX, TBX, TEX. And for 1 - 6 it should output TAX, TBX. And a four-digit number should start with one or two or three zeros

Comment: ^(([1-6][TAX|TBX]) | ([7][TAX|TBX|TEX])\s [0-9]{4})$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You almost got it. Try something like

```cs
using System;
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string text = "1TAX 1234\r\n7TEX 9876\r\n5TEX 9876\r\n4TBX 9876";
        string pattern = @"^(?:(?:[1-6]T[AB]X)|(?:7T[ABE]X))\s\d{4}";
        Regex r = new Regex(pattern, RegexOptions.Multiline);
        foreach (var m in r.Matches(text))
        {
            Console.WriteLine("> {0}", m.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: no $ at the end?

Comment: What is the very first"?:"?